# Could anyone please help me create / edit this powershell script

Tags: windows-10, powershell, psexec

1. I would like to reset the wsus service and delete the downloaded updates on selectable one or more hosts up to 200 Hosts.
2. I would like to ping the hosts and export into a file : excel with Online and Offline results.
3. The next wish is to have the Password part asterisked `***` when I type it.

   ```
   cls
   $User = Read-Host "Enter username"
   $Pass = Read-Host "Enter password"
   cls
   ```

4 it would be good to copy the `psexec` into everyone's host on `C:\temp` if its needed.

I have created a bat file to reset the WSUS service and delete the downloaded updates.

```
clean_wsus.bat file:
net stop wuauserv 
net stop bits 
cd\ 
cd C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution 
del *.* /s /q 
net start wuauserv 
net start bits
wuauclt /resetauthorization /detectnow
```

This works fine on one host.

This is the powershell script:

```
$input = Read-Host @"
Select Option
(1)Manually enter computer(s)
(2)Retrieve computer(s) from file

Option
"@

If ($input -eq 1){
    $count = Read-Host "How many computers"
    $Computers = 1..$count
    $b=0;$c=1; ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {$Computers[$b] = Read-Host "Computer" $c; $b++; $c++}
} ElseIF ($input-eq 2) {
    $Computers = Read-Host "File"
    $Computers = Get-Content $Computers
} Else {
    write-host "Invalid Option"
    Exit
}

cls
$User = Read-Host "Enter username"
$Pass = Read-Host "Enter password"
cls
$PSExec = "C:\Temp\PsExec.exe" 
ForEach ($Computer in $Computers){
    & $PSExec \\$Computer -u $User -p $Pass -h "C:\Temp\clean_wsus.bat"
}
```

This is the error that I get:

```
PsExec v2.33 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2021 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

PsExec.exe : The handle is invalid.
At C:\Temp\WSUS\Script\WSUS Update.ps1:31 char:1
+ & $PSExec \\$Computer -u $User -p $Pass -h "C:\Temp\clean_wsus.bat"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The handle is invalid.:String) [], RemoteExce 
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer.
Connecting to local system...

Connecting to local system...


Starting PSEXESVC service on local system...


Copying authentication key to NB***...


Connecting with PsExec service on NB***..


Starting C:\Temp\clean_wsus.bat on NB***....


Couldn't install PSEXESVC service:
PsExec could not start C:\Temp\clean_wsus.bat on NB***.:
```

Comment: For #3, see: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-7.1#example-2--save-console-input-as-a-secure-string and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertfrom-securestring?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: Why does this with batch and psexec to begin with? Use `Invoke-Command -Computer <pcnamehere> -Scriptblock { Powershell commands } -Credential (Get-Credential)`. I would convert all the batch logic to PowerShell and run it on the remote machine via the scriptblock in `invoke-command`. You can google for `invoke-ping` and it will ping with a quicker timeout than regular ping. You could built the list this way with the invoke-ping first, create the csv, excel, etc. and then run the commands against machines that were accessible via ping.